# Firebase functions: logging with winston in stackdriver console

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, logging, winston

I cannot make [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) logger to write logs to [stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) console. I deploy my functions as google firebase functions (using [`firebase deploy`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deployment)). `console` logging works fine, but we don't use such tool in the project.

What I tried:

- output to stderr using https://github.com/greglearns/winston-stderr
- using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston (both `winston.add(require('@google-cloud/logging-winston')); winston.log('error', 'Winston error!');` and also adding with parameters such as project ID `projectId` / service account JSON credentials file `keyFilename`);
- using https://github.com/findanyemail/winston-transport-stackdriver-error-reporting . Also no luck. I still cannot see logs in stackdriver.

Please suggest... I'm tired of experiments (each re-deploy takes time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally what I did - implemented [custom transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#adding-custom-transports) which actually calls `console.log` under the hood. This helped.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const util = require('util');
const ClassicConsoleLoggerTransport = winston.transports.CustomLogger = function (options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.name = 'ClassicConsoleLoggerTransport';
    this.level = options.level || 'info';
    // Configure your storage backing as you see fit
};
util.inherits(ClassicConsoleLoggerTransport, winston.Transport);

ClassicConsoleLoggerTransport.prototype.log = function (level, msg, meta, callback) {
    let args = [msg, '---', meta];
    switch (level) {
        case 'verbose':
        case 'debug':
            console.log.apply(null, args);
            break;
        case 'notice':
        case 'info':
            console.info.apply(null, args);
            break;
        case 'warn':
        case 'warning':
            console.warn.apply(null, args);
            break;
        case 'error':
        case 'crit':
        case 'alert':
        case 'emerg':
            console.error.apply(null, args);
            break;
        default:
            console.log.apply(null, args);
    }
    callback(null, true);
};
```

Comment: Can you add required files and how to use as a gist in github?

Answer (score 2):

Winston's default Console transport fails because it uses `console._stdout.write` when it's available, which is not accepted by Firebase Functions.

There's now a [Google Cloud transport package for Stackdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston) you can try.  Haven't used it and it requires node `^8.11.2` if you're using Winston 3.

Answer (score 0):

Docs for node.js winston setup are [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston)

I've added my full `logger.js` setup below.

The important bit is:

```
const format = winston.format.combine(winston.format.colorize({ all: true }))
const console = new winston.transports.Console({ format: winston.format.combine(format) })

const options = this.#explicitSetup ? { projectId: appConfig.firebase.options.projectId, keyFilename: `${rootDirname}/service-account-file.json` } : {}
const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston(options)

const transports = emulators ? [console] : [console, loggingWinston]

this.#logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: this.#defaultLevel,
  transports
})
```

Basically, if the emulators are running then use the console logger else use the console logger and the stack driver transports. You can check if the emulators are running by pinging a functions endpoint (e.g. a /ping endpoint you have created) on localhost. If it does not exist then the emulators are not running or this is a production environment. Notice also the ability to use an explicit setup whereby the `projectId` and `keyFilename` are passed in.

The JSON file for `keyFilename` can be created here:

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

My full `logger.js` code, in case it helps, follows:

```
import winston from 'winston'
import { LoggingWinston } from '@google-cloud/logging-winston'
import { appConfig } from '../app-config.js'
import { rootDirname } from './root-dirname.js'
import { isObjectLike } from 'lodash-es'

// https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs

export class Logger {

  #logger
  #defaultLevel = 'debug'
  #explicitSetup = false

  constructor() {
    this.error = this.error.bind(this)
    this.warn = this.warn.bind(this)
    this.info = this.info.bind(this)
    this.debug = this.debug.bind(this)
    this.log = this.log.bind(this)
  }

  init(emulators) {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/64173978/1205871
    winston.addColors({
      error: 'red',
      warn: 'yellow',
      info: 'bold cyan',
      debug: 'bold green'
    })

    const format = winston.format.combine(winston.format.colorize({ all: true }))
    const console = new winston.transports.Console({ format: winston.format.combine(format) })

    const options = this.#explicitSetup ? { projectId: appConfig.firebase.options.projectId, keyFilename: `${rootDirname}/service-account-file.json` } : {}
    const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston(options)

    const transports = emulators ? [console] : [console, loggingWinston]

    this.#logger = winston.createLogger({
      level: this.#defaultLevel,
      transports
    })
  }

  error(...args) {
    this.#logger.error(this.#argsToString(args))
  }

  warn(...args) {
    this.#logger.warn(this.#argsToString(args))
  }

  info(...args) {
    this.#logger.info(this.#argsToString(args))
  }

  debug(...args) {
    this.#logger.debug(this.#argsToString(args))
  }

  log(...args) {
    this.#logger[this.#defaultLevel](this.#argsToString(args))
  }

  #argsToString(args) {
    return args.map(arg => {
      const str = isObjectLike(arg) ? JSON.stringify(arg) : arg.toString()
      return str.trim()
    }).join(' \u2022\u2022 ')
  }
}

const blogger = new Logger()
export const logger = blogger
```